# why are horizontal and vertical stresses on an element in soil mass considered as principal stresses?

Tags: civil-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, retaining-wall

Despite the fact that there are shear stresses also involved while considering deformations in soil why are the horizontal and vertical stresses on an element as shown in below figure considered as principle stresses while analyzing the active and passive earth pressures on retaining walls? In other words how does one conclude here in the first place that shear stresses on horizontal and vertical planes are zero when the soil mass is in active or passive stage?

[image]

Comment: Because they come from the forces that need to be resolved. Barnes Wallis used those to good effect…

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: how doe one conclude here that there are no shear stresses on vertical and horizontal planes?

Comment: Why change the question? This is not a chat site.

Comment: why provide an option to edit then if changing or rather adding sth to question not expectd?

Comment: Edit to add detail to the original question, not add 5 million others. Perhaps take the Tour and see how to accept answers to your questions as well. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Are the principal stresses in question in the retaining wall or in the soil held by it? The principal directions are correct for the soil.

Comment: yes in the soil mass

Comment: @solar mike u shud get ur self checked smwhere as u seeem to suffer hallucinations. one or two edits seem 5 million to u.

Comment: @solar mike and yes if u dont know the answer don't comment unnecesarily since  its not a chat site. So keep mum. ok

Answer (score 0):

These are not principal stresses in the element. In my opinion this is simply a way of conveniently showing the stresses applied on the element, but not necessarily the principal ones (remember a triaxial test. Of course then the weakest plane on the element will be sloped). Showing stresses vertical and horizontal is convenient and can take us to solutions when solving the retaining wall.